# Can't change the filename using Gold Raccoon IO7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ftp, uiimage

Im using [Gold Raccoon](https://github.com/albertodebortoli/GoldRaccoon) to upload some images to a FTP server

When I execute this function I can't seem to change the name,if i put any other thing that is not a literal,the image won't upload,Is there any way I can keep the FileName as a variable?

```
-(void)UploadImage:(NSString *)BDPath :(NSString*)Filename{
[self _setupManager];
[self.requestsManager addRequestForUploadFileAtLocalPath:BDPath toRemotePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Filename]];
[self.requestsManager startProcessingRequests];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it

```
-(void)UploadImage:(NSString *)BDPath :(NSString*)Filename{
[self _setupManager];
[self.requestsManager addRequestForUploadFileAtLocalPath:BDPath toRemotePath:Filename];
[self.requestsManager startProcessingRequests];
}
```